# Order by a meta field in query loop

Tags: custom-field, loop, post-meta, sort

I would like to sort my article from a category by a number added in a meta field.

Here is the first step, I get the articles to display on the page.

```
<?php
    $cat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cat_page', true );
?>
```

I begin the loop. This is on this loop I get my custom meta field.

```
<?php if ( $cat ) {
    // run the custom query
    $query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=' . $cat );

    // run the custom loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta', true ); ?>
```

**But how sort by a specific key of the meta (-> $my_meta['niveau-chiffre'])**

I tried something like this

```
<?php
    $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta', true );
    $cat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cat_page', true );

    $args = array(
        'category_name' => $cat,
        'meta_key' => '_my_meta',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
               'key' => '_my_meta',
               'value' => 'niveau-chiffre',
               'meta_value' => 'niveau-chiffre',
               'compare' => '>=',
               'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

And the loop

```
<?php if ( $cat ) {
    // run the custom query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // run the custom loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); $my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta', true ); ?>
```

But at this point, I think the meta variables (_my_meta) ain't got.

**EDIT**

My meta looks like to this in the data base

[image: screen database]

And I tried something like this thanks to [Generate WP](http://generatewp.com/wp_query/)

```
<?php
    $cat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cat_page', true );

    $args = array(
        'category_name' => $cat,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
               'key' => '_my_meta',
               'value' => 'niveau-chiffre',
               'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
    );
?>
```

but it didn't work either.

Comment: Have you debugged to see what your code is producing? Are you seeing posts returned or not?

Comment: Articles are well displayed, but not sort by the 'niveau-chiffre' meta, and I tried to var_dump my meta before the loop, but it didn't works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cat_page', true );

$args = array(
    'category_name' => $cat,
    'meta_key' => 'niveau_chiffre',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', //Since we're dealing with numbers
    'order' => 'ASC',
    //'meta_query' => array(
       // array(
           //'key' => 'niveau-chiffre',
           //'value' => 'niveau-chiffre', Don't give a value because we're not looking for a specific one
           //'compare' => '>=', We're not comparing as such. Defaults to =
           //'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        //)
    ), //You missed a comma here I think
);
```

Try this.

Comment: Not working at all, there isn't posts displayed.

Comment: Turn on WP debugging to see if there are any errors

Comment: With this line `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` ?

Comment: Yeah, amongst [others](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: Try entering the category name in args array: 'category_name' => 'name_of_category'

Comment: Okay, I turn on the Dubug mode, but nothing display. 2 things about your lasts comments. First of all, the 'niveau-chiffre` is a meta_value on the meta_key `_my_meta` (according to my phpmyadmin). Moreover, The category_name is not the same all the time, that's why I must get it depending to another post_meta.

Comment: What is the name of your custom field? That is what we need to query by. I recommend using [Generate WP](http://generatewp.com/) to generate a custom query without risking any syntax errors. You'll only need to modify 'category_name' to your variable. If things still don't work, you need to check you get output from your custom field using `get_post_meta($id, 'niveau_chiffre')`.

Comment: But I don't want to order by the `category_name`, I want to order by another meta field and this is $my_meta. I tried to play with your tool, but actually it doesn't work.
EDIT : and more, I don't use the default meta field by Wordpress, but my own solution to add custom field on post.

Comment: I know you don't want to order that way, but you need that parameter to call the correct set of posts. The tool DOES work, you need to hit Update Code to generate code, but never mind.
I think the problem is perhaps the way you are creating and saving custom field values. First, work out how to access the data for your custom fields, then you'll be able to add that into your `WP_Query`.

Comment: Sure, the website works pretty well, I added a custom field and tried to copy/paste on my own code, but that this part who didn't work. I updated my first post to see what I've tried and how my meta are set on my database.

Answer (score -1):

`orderby` should be `meta_value_num`, or `meta_value`, not the name of the key. See [WP_Query orderby parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: And that's what I wrote, isn't it ?

Answer (score -2):

Your meta data is array, which means it is stored in database in serialized form. You cannot [cleanly and easily] query serialized data. It would make sense to refactor to store value flat in field with `niveau-chiffre` key.

Comment: This is what I did, I created a new meta field only for this value, but the value is duplicate, because I should kept from the array.